# Iniciar animação quando a DIV estiver visível

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inseri em minha página alguns gráficos de pizza animados, mas gostaria que a animação só fosse iniciada quando a DIV que comporta esses gráficos fosse exibida na tela, alguém saberia como fazer isso?

A animação a seguir deveria ser iniciada quando a DIV com os gráficos ficasse visível:

```
$('#pie-one,#pie-two,#pie-tree').pieChart({
        barColor: '#21d927',
        trackColor: '#eee',
        lineCap: 'square',
        lineWidth: 18,
        onStep: function (from, to, percent) {
            $(this.element).find('.pie-value').text(Math.round(percent) + '%');
        }
    });
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Poderia colocar na pergunta um [mcve] demonstrando esse comportamento?

Comment: Inseri o script que realiza a animação, o plugin tem o nome de pie-chart, isso ajuda?

Comment: Qual é a div com os gráficos?

Comment: Quando e como ela fica visível na tela?

Comment: Ela fica visível quando rolar a página até ela.

Comment: Mas vc quer que a animação aconteça assim que a div aparecer um pouquinho, no meio, um pouco, tudo?

Comment: O ideal seria quando ela estiver pelo menos metade visível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O script abaixo verifica se a `div` `teste` (substitua `teste` pelo `id` da sua `div`) está visível na janela de acordo com a porcentagem especificada e chama a ação:

```js
$(window).on("scroll load",function(){
 var aparecer = 50; // porcentagem (neste caso, é a metade, 50%)
 var eleHeight = $('#teste').outerHeight(); // altura da div
 var eleTopo = $('#teste').offset().top; // distancia da div ao topo do documento
 var scrlTopo = $(window).scrollTop(); // quanto foi rolada a janela
 var distance = eleTopo-scrlTopo; // distancia da div ao topo da janela
 var altJanela = window.innerHeight; // altura da janela

 if(distance <= altJanela-(eleHeight*(aparecer/100))) {
  $("#teste").html("div visível"); // só para exemplo, pode apagar esta linha e descomentar as linhas abaixo
//  $('#pie-one,#pie-two,#pie-tree').pieChart({
//   barColor: '#21d927',
//   trackColor: '#eee',
//   lineCap: 'square',
//   lineWidth: 18,
//   onStep: function (from, to, percent) {
//    $(this.element).find('.pie-value').text(Math.round(percent) + '%');
//   }
//  });
 }
});
```

```css
#teste{
 display: block; width: 300px; height: 100px; background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Role para baixo
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="teste">
</div>
```

Comment: Meu amigo DvD, perfeito! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Tente colocar o seu código dentro de um bloco assim:

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
 //Seu código 

});
```

Source: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/