# Ao rolar a pagina e chegar em uma determinada DIV a cor de fundo da mesma mudasse

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de quando alguém rolar a pagina e chegar em uma determinada DIV a cor de fundo da mesma mudasse tentei fazer assim:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lv29w75/9/)

mas não deu certo. Qual seria a forma correta de se fazer?

Obs: O site sera responsivo logo scrollTop: 50px não iria funcionar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já havia respondido questão semelhante **[aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/251441/8063)**.

Para fazer isso, tem que calcular a distância do elemento até o topo do documento menos o scroll, e subtrair pela altura visível da janela.

Adicionei uma variável `aparecer` que é a porcentagem em que o elemento estiver visível na janela para alterar a cor de fundo:

```js
$(window).on("scroll",function(){
 var aparecer = 50; // porcentagem (neste caso, é a metade, 50%)
 var eleHeight = $('#div').outerHeight(); // altura da div
 var eleTopo = $('#div').offset().top; // distancia da div ao topo do documento
 var scrlTopo = $(window).scrollTop(); // quanto foi rolada a janela
 var distance = eleTopo-scrlTopo; // distancia da div ao topo da janela
 var altJanela = window.innerHeight; // altura da janela

 if(distance <= altJanela-(eleHeight*(aparecer/100))) {
  $("#div").css("background","blue");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Role para baixo
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="div" style="display: block; width: 300px; height: 200px; background: red;">
 Texto texto texto texto
</div>
```

Comment: pq aparacer e dividido por cem?

Comment: se eu quiser alterar a cor novamente quando a pessoa subir a pagina e so eu por um else correto?

Comment: @LucasSimao Isso mesmo

Comment: tanks agora e guardar isso na minha cabeça